# TeamCity NUnit test result visualisation

Tags: nunit, nant, teamcity

Is there any way to produce visual results of NUnit tests from within TeamCity's "Tests" tab, currently my NAnt script outputs an .xml file of the results using the following task:

```
<nunit2 haltonfailure="false" failonerror="false" verbose="true">
  <formatter type="Xml" extension=".xml" outputdir="${tests.output.dir}" usefile="true" />
  <test assemblyname="${assemblies.output.dir}/TestApp.Tests.dll" />
</nunit2>
```

TIA

Answer (score 6):

It can be done using TeamCity [import data](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TW/XML+Test+Reporting) service message:

Print to the console the next message:

`##teamcity[importData type='nunit' path='xml results path']`

'xml results path' should point to the path where nunit placed the test results.

By the way, you can use TeamCity [nunit launcher](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2008/09/24/using-teamcity-nunit-launcher/) to execute and report tests automatically.